# How to create a function in powershell that runs a macro in an Excel workbook?

Tags: excel, powershell

How do I create a function in powershell that runs a macro in an Excel workbook?

I've tried the following:

```
Function xlRunMacro($excel, $macroname){
    try{
    $excel.Run($macroname)
    }catch{
        echo $error
        $key = 'Open-Excel';
        $date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        Log-Error $key $date;
        $error.Clear()
    }
}

$macroname = "'delete_old'"

$setexcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$currentworkbook = $setexcel.Workbooks.Open("${paths}${files}")
xlRunMacro($setexcel, $macroname)
```

However, I get this error:
**Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Run'.**

Any ideas please?

Comment: you are calling the function incorrectly. leave off the `()` when you call it ... otherwise you are sending in ONE array, not TWO objects.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, if I may make a slight correction, you can call a function using `()`; just not recommended due to it's ambiguous nature of calling parameters - *personally dislike it's implementation*.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - from what i have seen - doing `FuncName($ParamOne, $ParamTwo)`  feeds the pair of items _as one object - an array_ into the 1st parameter of the function. so you CAN do it wrong, but it is still WRONG since it gives the wrong result. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, good to know!

Comment: glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

As @Lee_Dailey mentioned, params need to be separated.

To be on the safe side generally, it's a good idea for functions to accept params by name rather than position.

e.g.

```
Function xlRunMacro{
    param(
        $excel,
        [string]$macroname
    )
    $excel.Run($macroname)
}

xlRunMacro -excel $setexcel -macroname $macroname
```